# RelayCommand in ViewModel does not contain the Listbox object bound in the XAML Command

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm-light

Menu.Pages is filled with this:

```
        this.Menu = new Menu()
        {
            Pages = new List<Page>()
            {
                new Page() {
                    Title = "ergre",
                    URI = "rgerg"
                },
                new Page() {
                    Title = "herth",
                    URI = "wefwe"
                }
            }
        };
```

I have the following XAML:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             x:Name="Pages"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Menu.Pages}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Pages, Path=DataContext.ButtonCommand_LoadGagPage}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The Command that is bound to the button correctly fires off the following method:

```
...    
ButtonCommand_LoadGagPage = new RelayCommand<Page>((param) => ButtonCommand_ExecuteLoadGagPage(param));    
...


public RelayCommand<Page> ButtonCommand_LoadGagPage
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public void ButtonCommand_ExecuteLoadGagPage(Page page)
{
    // page is null :( ?
}
```

However, the page variable does not contain the page. How do i connect the object up correctly...

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to place CommandParamter attribute on. The following resolved the issue!

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Pages, Path=DataContext.ButtonCommand_LoadGagPage}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```